# nagios plug-in for collecting DNS stats not working on RHEL server 6.7

Tags: dns, bind, nagios

We are trying to get the check_bind.sh script to automatically update the named.stats file. However, the file only seems to update when we run the script manually or with a cron job. We have this installed on RHEL server 6.7 running Bind 9.8.2. My understanding is that the plug-in runs at certain intervals on its own which in turn auto- populates the stats. Any help or to get this going would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Typically nagios plugins require nagios configuration, so that nagios calls them periodically. How have you configured nagios?

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like a permissions issue. Do you run it manually as the nagios user?

Comment: thrig - yes, we have. However its not polling this particular box where I have the check_bind.sh plugin configured. Perhaps that is my next step. @Jeff - Correct, right now I run it manually as the nagios user, who owns the file. Or like I said we can get it to update via a cron job.

Comment: Also, just for clarification, the check_bind.sh plugin is installed on the actual DNS server, not the nagios server. Should I have the plugin installed on the nagios server?